# WillPopScope does not work for me, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, stack

I have 4 different items in my bottom navigation menu and in one case I need to navigate to one page and delete all the pages in my stack so that I use this code to navigate my another screen;

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) => AnamenuTemelSayfa(currentIndex: 2),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) => Container(child: child),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  ),
  (_) => true,
);
```

After this navigation when I hit the back button on the physical device it backs to the last screen that I've just came, to handle with this problem I change true value into false but when I do it after this navigation event in any pages of the app on the physical device back button does not work so that I try to do another thing is that to wrap second page with WillPopScope not to go back I've defined this code;

```
//Second page
onWillPop: () async {
  return await Future.value(false);
},
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry for defining my problem. This is my problem 

"When i navigate to another screen with the code above it should delete all the pages in my stack not to able to use back button on the physical device"

Answer (score 0):

if you want use willpopscope you should use `Navigator.push` instead of `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil`

**pushAndRemoveUntil** remove all pages until your current page then you cant go back to previous page and your **WillPopScope** not calling, so if you want prevent user to back to previous page you should wrap your scaffold with WillPopScope widget like this:

```
WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: Scaffold(
              // your code here
          )
    )
```

**EDIT:**
use this navigator (it`s remove all page until YourNewPage)

```
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context){
      return YourNewPage();
    }), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly what i need, 
**"Delete all pages in my stack after navigate to seocnd page".** 
That's why i defined WillPopScope and pushAndRemoveUntil not to have a chance to go back but still it navigates to previous screen.

Comment: Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(bcontext,PageRouteBuilder(
pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) => AnamenuTemelSayfa (currentIndex: 2),
transitionsBuilder: (context,anim1,anim2,child) => Container (child: child),
transitionDuration: Duration ( milliseconds: 200 ), ),( Route<dynamic> route) => false);




I needed to change **MaterialPageRoute** into **PageBuilder** because i send my current context to the root of the custom navigation package to change switch my bottom navigation item

Comment: can you send a picture from your application ? or send your codes

Comment: it's a special project sir so that i cannot send all of them but if you tell me what you need to see exactly i can send them with paste of code

Comment: i want to see your bottom navigation items and prefer screenshot and code together

Comment: ~~~https:/ /paste .ofcode.o rg/ gTQb ssD7u Rru Fpu4v cqG jb~~~ i hope it can help you (please delete spaces inside of the link)

Comment: why you customize navigator and scaffold ? and why you not use pageview widget its simple and i think it can solve your problem because you use a page controller for routing instead of push and pop

Comment: Sir, i didn't know how to solve disappearing problem for navigation bar when you go deeper in a menu in a page so that i've searched and found custom navigation package to solve this problem then i kept using navigation things like navigator.push,pushAndRemove as i need etc. That's why i did not need to use pageview till now. So what can you recommend me after this time to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your route predicate should return `false` to remove all the previous page and push new page.

```
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2) => AnamenuTemelSayfa(currentIndex: 2),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) => Container(child: child),
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  ),
  (_) => false, // routePredicate
);
```

And now you don't need to use `WillPopScope`.

Comment: You are right, i've tried it before then back button never works in the application. Is there any way to make it true when i navigate to another page